# Inquiry2 is undefined with react-native-persona

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, persona

I’m trying to integrate Persona into my React Native project, but the [documentation](https://docs.withpersona.com/docs/react-native-sdk-integration) seems to be messed up. It says use `Inquiry2.fromTemplate` to begin the inquiry, but they import `Inquiry`.

Importing `Inquiry2` is also of no use because it gives an error about something being required (even though all arguments are provided). Could someone who has successfully integrated Persona help me out by letting me know what I’m supposed to be importing and using to begin an Inquiry?

Comment: It looks like they have 2 incompatible versions.  What version are you using?  You need to look at the correct documentation for the version you're using.

Comment: I’m using version 2 and version 2 documentation. In the V2 docs it says Inquiry2 (which I assume means V2), but they don’t import that which creates an error.